# Executing powershell script using OdiOSCommand

Tags: powershell, batch-file, oracle-data-integrator

I created a batch file which firstly invokes cmd, then it should invoke powershell, read a specific file, and create a new file which encodes it to UTF-8. Executing this script manually it works fine.

Oracle Data Integrator supports OSCommands, so im using that element to call the batch script which I created for that purpose(automation reasons). Below you can find the code of the batch script:

```
cmd 
powershell
"Get-Content D:\mrapateatrit\SOURCE_FILES\Puntoret.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 D:\mrapateatrit\SOURCE_FILES\Puntoret_utf8.txt"
exit;
```

When I execute the ODI package which calls this script, it outputs this to file:

```
C:\Users\lori\Desktop>cmd  
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\lori\Desktop>
```

This means that its only invoking cmd in the code, but it is not reading the powershell command. 
Some of the parameters which this element can take:

```
Command to execute: I provided the path of the batch script
Output file directory: path provided
Error file directory: Error file path provided
Working directory: desktop path provided
```

If someone could help me to create the ideal way to call that script through ODI would be really helpful

Comment: Check if you can use this `cmd /c powershell -command "Get-Content D:\mrapateatrit\SOURCE_FILES\Puntoret.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 D:\mrapateatrit\SOURCE_FILES\Puntoret_utf8.txt"
exit;`

Comment: @Mudit, I don't see a reason for the `exit`; _`cmd /c` will exit after the last command has run!_

Comment: @Compo You are correct. I copied code from answer, replaced first 2 lines and pasted it back in comment. Thanks!

Comment: @MuditBahedia , your solution works fine when executing the batch file manually, but when ODI executes it powershell command is unknown, it writes this in error file:
 'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @LorikBerisha See if this works: `cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "Get-Content D:\mrapateatrit\SOURCE_FILES\Puntoret.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 D:\mrapateatrit\SOURCE_FILES\Puntoret_utf8.txt"`

Comment: @MuditBahedia sir yes sir, it is working now! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using below code solved the issue:
`cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "Get-Content D:\mrapateatrit\SOURCE_FILES\Puntoret.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 D:\mrapateatrit\SOURCE_FILES\Puntoret_utf8.txt"`